# regex - match character in between strings and everywhere

Tags: php, regex

```
@name "@new other content" "@" @here and here@
```

I want to match all the "**@**" excluding the ones in between quotes.

I tried:

```
(?!\")\@(?!\")
```

It works partially, does not match "@" but does match "@new other content".

I am using with "preg_replace" in PHP.

Thanks for any help.

UPDATE:

In this case I want to match the @ on:  `@name, @here, here@` only...

Comment: What should be matched by `Outside @ " in @ side " outside @"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the "@" is always directly after the " then you can use

```
(?<!\")\@
```

Your `(?!\")\@(?!\")` is wrong at that point, it has to be a negative lookbehind assertion (`(?<!...)`). and the following lookahead assertion is only failing, if the "@" is directly followed by a ".

If the "@" can be anywhere between quotation marks, then it is not possible with regex in php.

Under the assumption, that the quotes are always balanced you can try this

```
[^"\s]*@[^"\s]*(?=[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?32q1d)

This simply matches a substring that contains a @, when there is an even amount of " ahead.

**Be careful:** it will fail when there is an unmatched quotation mark anywhere in the string.

Comment: Thanks. I can't assume that case... it should match @ in any place in  between the double quotes.

Comment: @MarizMelo: I added another solution.